# Android : How to remove bottom overflow menu

Tags: android, toolbar

I want to remove this thing that shows in Android 5.0 in bottom with menu and back item (see the picture). Even if I don't include toolbar or menu in code, it's still shows. Also I removed toolbar in xml layout if that even depends on it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaxxw.png

Comment: Set your minimum sdk version to 14(11 will do too I suppose) or above. It is for sure lower than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to remove bottom overflow menu

[Set your targetSdkVersion to 14 or higher.](https://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html)

> ```
> Preferably without raising the targetSdkVersion?
> ```

Chop the bottom portion of the phone off with a very sharp axe. Note that this may void your warranty on the phone.

Comment: thanks, it's working now. I only changed targedSdkVersion from 22 to 18. :)

Answer (score -1):

1. update your AndroidManifest.xml
2. update targetSdkVersion to 13+